# Bootstrap Mvc.Grid for .NET MVC not accepting complex model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, grid-layout

I am building a small Asp.NET MVC web application for document management system where I need to keep track of all the changes that happened with files and folders in jsTree (jQuery implementation of a tree control).
I have found Mvc.GRID Bootstrap control that enables (very easily) a grid representation of data.  Let me describe what I did:

This is a model that partial view uses - `List<List<HistoryVM>>` and HistoryVM looks like this:

```
public class HistoryViewModel
{
  [Display(Name="Name")]
  string ItemName { get; set; }

  [Display(Name="Original Path")]
  public string ItemPath { get; set; }

  [Display(Name="Type")]
  public string ItemType { get; set; }

  [Display(Name="Author")]
  public string EventAuthorName { get; set; }

  [Display(Name="Comment")]
  public string EventActionDesc { get; set; }

  [Display(Name="Timestamp")]
  public DateTime DateOfEvent { get; set; }

  [Display(Name="Action Type")]
  public string ActionType { get; set; }
}
```

Controller looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ShowHistory(string path) 
{
  OperationService operations = new OperationService();  
  var historyRecord = operations.FindItemHistory(path);
  if (historyRecord != null & historyRecord.Count() > 0)
  {
    return PartialView("../Shared/Partial/ShowHistory", historyRecord);    
  }
  else
  {
    return PartialView("../Shared/Partial/ShowHistoryNoHistory"); 
  }
}
```

And finally this is the view:

```
@model   List<List<LaneWebApp.Models.HistoryViewModel>>
@using GridMvc.Html
@Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
<div>
  @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(c => { 
    c.Add(x => x.ElementAt(0).ItemType);
    c.Add(x => x.ElementAt(0).ItemName);
    c.Add(x => x.ElementAt(0).ItemPath);
    c.Add(x => x.ElementAt(0).EventAuthorName);
    c.Add(x => x.ElementAt(0).DateOfEvent.ToString());
    c.Add(x => x.ElementAt(0).EventActionDesc);
  })
</div>
```

Which gives me only the first element of each list. B**ut I would like to have all history records, not just the first one.**

How can I render this List of List in Grid.MVC?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like current version of Bootstrap Grid.MVC does not support complex models - take a look at the official site.
So, I had to come up with my own view and sorting.